# Version 7.x-4.7.24 I need to send letters to contributors that gives them detailed information on each donation they have made for the year

Tags: civicontribute, receipts

I looked in several places.  One answer said to go to Find Contributions, actions, Thank-you letters for contributors, Group Contributions by contact.  When I follow those instructions I do not find a Thank-you letter in my actions.  Also, someone said that I may need to add an extension.  As I browsed through extensions under administration, system settings, extension, I wasn't sure which to use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* an extension to do end of year receipts - though there are some that can help.

If you're based in Canada, you can generate a CRS-compliant receipt with [CDN Tax Receipts](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cdn-tax-receipts), which automates this whole process for you.  I believe a German equivalent exists as well.

Otherwise, there are instructions in the documentation called [grouped contribution thank-you letters](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous/).  That will get you a table of contributions.

Note that it seems like some of the display options are a little buggy; I just did some testing and found "horizontal table" to be the one that displayed best.  If you really need to get the formatting perfect, you can ask your sysadmin to enable Smarty processing for mail templates.  This is explained in the docs.

Note that despite the documentation, you do NOT need the Smarty processing if the only thing you need is a total.  Instead you can use the [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) extension.  It will give you a token called "Total Contributions this Year".  This is the easiest way to add a total to the receipt.

Finally - I can't speak to why you're not seeing a thank-you action.  It should appear per my first screenshot below.  Please post a new question (with a screenshot) if you're still having trouble with that.

[image]

"[image: CiviCRM menu highlighting "Find Contributions"]

Answer (score 0):

This extension https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.entitymessages comes with a token that I use
{entitymessages.Domain__thank_you_letter_summary_block}
with a block of donations over the year